# Will Activity onpause be called when switching between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Right now I have 2 activities. When the second activity is running, the first activity onpause is clicked which means  I have to unregister all the listeners (which is not what I want when the app is running, I just wanted them unregistered when the app is in the background).

So would it make sense for me to create 2 fragments with one activity. Then  I can unregister the listener when the activity onpause is called (only when app goes to background) but it won't be called when fragments are switched.

Is my understanding correct?
Thank you

Comment: Yups `onPause()` would not be called when switching fragments.

Comment: fragments are contained in an activity..

Comment: Thank you Put it as answer so I can accept it

Comment: What!? onPause of fragment will be called not activity onPause.

Comment: @Rohit5k2: Yes, it will be called on the fragment. I thought that was what was being discussed. Of course, you're correct that there will be no callback on the managing activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on the activity that you have used to launch your fragment . If two fragments A and B belong to the same activity, then the moment you switch view from Fragment A to Fragment B, your activity does not go to a paused state, means onPause() won't be called, but is still running which is ideally providing the view for Fragment B.

So, you do not need to **unregister** the listener on change of Fragment in the same activity.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I downvoted it due to a misunderstanding, but can't reverse it now, unless the answer is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yups Activity onPause() would not be called when switching fragments.